# When I pass xml string as a request i get an Bad Request exception in WCF REST?

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

Client:

```
string value = "<?xml version=1.0?><person><firstname>john</firstname><lastname>smith</lastname> <person/>";

using (HttpResponseMessage response = m_RestHttpClient.Post("new/customerxml/"+value2, frm.CreateHttpContent()))
{

}
```

---

Server:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "new/customerxml/string={value}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public string NewCustomer(string value)
{
        return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because WCF sniffs the content and decides you are uploading XML, not a string.  Assuming you are using the HttpClient from the WCF REST Starter kit, try this:

```
    string value = "<?xml version=1.0?><person><firstname>john</firstname><lastname>smith</lastname> <person/>";

var content = HttpContentExtentions.CreateDataContract(value, typeof(string));
using (HttpResponseMessage response = m_RestHttpClient.Post("new/customerxml/"+value2, content)
    {
      ...
    }
```